# What is the pinout of this Toshiba SATA drive and does an adapter exist?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata, toshiba-hard-drive

I have a small Toshiba SATA drive from a laptop that uses a modified power connector.

Does anyone know the proper pinout of this, whether it has a name for the connector that I can reference, and whether an adapter exists to regular SATA?

The SATA connector is standard but the power portion of it is different.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably mini or micro SATA. Try comparing images from google with your drive. You can do it better with the drive in your hands.

Comment: Adapter>>>>https://www.amazon.com/Micro-SATA-1-8-2-5-Adapter/dp/B004HPDDG2